# Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum Runtime error 424

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use this code to hide rows from row 15 to row 59 if the 
`sumi` from B15 to K15 using `i` to index the rows from 15 to 59.  SEE BELOW

On the `sumi` line below I get a

> runtime error 424 "Object Required"

and I cannot see where the problems is.  I am sure it is something simple.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim sumi As Single

i = 15

Do Until i = 56
     StartRow = i
     EndRow = i

     Application.EnableEvents = True

     sumi = Aplication.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("B" & i & ":K" & i))

     Application.EnableEvents = False

     If sumi = "0" Then
          Rows("StartRow:RowEnd").EntireRow.Hidden = True
     ElseIf sumi > 0 Then
          Rows("StartRow:RowEnd").EntireRow.Hidden = False
          MsgBox " sumi = " & sumi
     End If
     Application.EnableEvents = True
     i = i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: You misspelled `Application`.

Comment: Also remove the quotes in `If sumi = "0" Then`

Comment: `Option Explicit` should be at the top of every module...

Answer (score 0):

other than what already pointed out in the comments, you also have to change `Rows("StartRow:RowEnd")` to `Rows(StartRow & ":" & RowEnd)`

but you could shorten the entire code down to:

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 15 To 56
    Rows(i).Hidden = (Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("B" & i & ":K" & i)) = 0)
Next
```

while if values in the relevant range are subject to formula calculation, then disable automatic calculation for the loop being and then bring it back at the end:

```
Dim i As Integer

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual ' to prevent row height adjustement
For i = 15 To 56
    Rows(i).Hidden = (Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("B" & i & ":K" & i)) = 0)
Next
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Comment: Thank you - the reduced code method worked perfectly.  I do have a couple of quick questions - I have "Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)" and combo boxes.  When I step through the coded and go to combobox it performs 1 of several steps and then keeps going back to Sub Worksheet Change and back and forth until the combox box is complete.  Seem like a crazy process.  Does it have anything to do with the Application.EnableEvents = True or false setting within the code areas????

Comment: You are welcome. You may then consider marking the answer as accepted. Thank you. As for the _crazy process_ try and wrap the code in between “Application.EnableEvents = False” and “Application.EnableEvents = True“ statements, to avoid any sheet change calling your  Worksheet_Change sub

Comment: Thanks again - I will try to wrap code between Application.EnableEvents and see what happens. And I will find the place to mark the answer as accepted.